# Pseudo-random Number generation for Passwords

Tags: passwords, random-number-generator, pseudo-random-function

I am looking for a good pseudo-random number generation algorithm for passwords.

My scenario is that I have to generate 5K pseudo-random bits from a user-supplied password (6 characters). What are possible options and which one would be able to cover for my purposes?

Comment: with 6 characters you're doomed. Even with optimistic assumptions that's merely 36 bits of entropy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html) is the best function for key-stretching we have. With such a bad password, you'll need all the stretching you can get, so make sure to use a large work parameter and a fast implementation.

But you should really consider using a stronger password. 10 random characters are *much* better than only 6.

Comment: thanks. but i am talking about algorithmic perspective not from the coding perspective. What are other possible options and why do you recommend some specific option?